# Border and padding between caracteres in EditText Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext

Currently my application has several edittext to build a single field. Is it possible to create an EditText with a design that looks similar to this?

Ex:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnVqf.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Of course `MaskedEdittext` library can do this for you easily**

- https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext

*Or you can do this by adding a TextWatcher on your edittext and add a breakpoint character to Edittext after specific number of character input*